# JOLT transformation with two level nested array objects

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

I want to use Jolt Shift to transform below input to a desire output. The input have two level array nested. Please help me out if you have a solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Input:

```json
{
  "P": {
    "type": "manager",
    "metadata": {
      "id": "mgr1"
    },
    "properties": {
      "firstName": "managerFirstName",
      "lastName": "managerLastName",
      "employmentId": "employmentId"
    },
    "S": [
      {
        "type": "employee",
        "metadata": {
          "id": "empl1"
        },
        "properties": {
          "last": "employeeOneLastName",
          "first": "employeeOneFirstName"
        },
        "S": [
          {
            "type": "address",
            "metadata": {
              "identifier": "addr1"
            },
            "properties": {
              "city": "addressOneCity",
              "street": "addressOneStreet"
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "address",
            "metadata": {
              "id": "addr2"
            },
            "properties": {
              "city": "addressTwoCity",
              "street": "addressTwoStreet"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "employee",
        "metadata": {
          "id": "empl2"
        },
        "properties": {
          "last": "employeeTwoLastName",
          "first": "employeeTwoFirstName"
        },
        "S": [
          {
            "type": "address",
            "metadata": {
              "id": "addr3"
            },
            "properties": {
              "city": "addressThreeCity",
              "street": "addressThreeStreet"
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "address",
            "metadata": {
              "id": "addr4"
            },
            "properties": {
              "city": "addressFourCity",
              "street": "addressFourStreet"
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "address",
            "metadata": {
              "id": "addr5"
            },
            "properties": {
              "city": "addressFiveCity",
              "street": "addressFiveStreet"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "officeinfo",
        "metadata": {
          "id": "office1"
        },
        "properties": {
          "country": "myCountry",
          "city": "myCity",
          "employmentId": "employmentId"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Desired Output:

```json
{
  "manager": {
    "type": "manager",
    "firstName": "managerFirstName",
    "lastName": "managerLastName",
    "employmentId": "employmentId",
    "employee": [
      {
        "type": "employee",
        "lastName": "employeeOneLastName",
        "firstName": "employeeOneFirstName",
        "address": [
          {
            "type": "address",
            "city": "addressOneCity",
            "street": "addressOneStreet"
          },
          {
            "type": "address",
            "city": "addressTwoCity",
            "street": "addressTwoStreet"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "address": [
          {
            "city": "addressTwoCity",
            "street": "addressThreeStreet",
            "type": "address"
          },
          {
            "type": "address",
            "city": "addressFourCity",
            "street": "addressFourStreet"
          },
          {
            "city": "addressFiveCity",
            "street": "addressFiveStreet",
            "type": "address"
          }
        ],
        "type": "employee",
        "lastName": "employeeTwoLastName",
        "firstName": "employeeTwoFirstName"
      }
    ],
    "office": {
      "type": "officeinfo",
      "country": "myCountry",
      "city": "myCity",
      "employmentId": "employmentId"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my spec which is not working as desired. The addresses associated with the employee is not correct. Notice the employeeOne should have both address One and Two, and the employeeTwo should have the address of Three, Four, and Five.

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "P": {
        "type": "manager.&",
        "properties": {
          "firstName": "manager.firstName",
          "lastName": "manager.lastName",
          "employmentId": "manager.employmentId"
        },
        "S": {
          "*": {
            "type": {
              "officeinfo": {
                "$": "manager.office.type"
              },
              "employee": {
                "$": "manager.employee[&3].type"
              }
            },
            "*": {
              "last": "manager.employee[&2].lastName",
              "first": "manager.employee[&2].firstName",
              "country": "manager.office.country",
              "city": "manager.office.city",
              "employmentId": "manager.office.employmentId"
            },
            "S": {
              "*": {
                "type": "manager.employee[&3].address[&1].type",
                "*": {
                  "city": "manager.employee[&2].address[&4].city",
                  "street": "manager.employee[&2].address[&4].street"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=recursivelySquashNulls"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick is using **`@(<int>,type)`** at appropriate locations in order to separate the sub-objects and sub-arrays properly such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "type": "@(1,type).&", 
        "prop*": {
          "*": "@(2,type).&" 
        },
        "S": {
          "*": {
            "type": {
              "employee": {
                "@1": "@(5,type).&1[&3].&2" // count how many ":" and/or "{" chars should be traversed while going up the tree in order to reach the level of "type" to determine the <int>(it's 5 in this case)
              },
              "*info": {
                "@1": "@(5,type).&(1,1).&2" // "&(1,1)" represents the piece where "*" stays, so it's "office" in this case
              }
            },
            "prop*": {
              "*st": "@(4,type).@(2,type)[&2].&Name"
            },
            "S": {
              "*": {
                "prop*": {
                  "@(1,type)": "@(6,type).@(4,type)[&4].@(2,type)[&2].type",
                  "*": "@(6,type).@(4,type)[&4].@(2,type)[&2].&"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // stands for nothing but sorting
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "type": "&1.&",
        "firstName": "&1.&",
        "lastName": "&1.&",
        "employmentId": "&1.&",
        "employee": "&1.&",
        "offi*": "&1.&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Note that, no need to repeat the key names at right-hand-side of the key-value pairs in order to replicate them, but just use ampersands. Btw, the second shift transformation is just added to provide getting the desired order, eg. might be removed without affecting the currently handled transformation.

Comment: Thanks Barbaros Özhan for your quick help.  The result looks right to me. Now I would just need to deep dive in your solution to learn from it and see if any further question.  This is awesome and truly appreciated.  Chau

Comment: you're welcome @ChauNguyen , nice to help!

Comment: Hi Barbaros, I saw how you conditional the type (ie employee, *info), and using it as the output object name when traverse.  In case the "type" has additional prefix info, such as xxx_manager, xxx_employee, xxx_address, xxx_officeInfo. How do you fix the spec to deal with this requirement and coming out with the same result but still keep the type output in convention xxx_...?  Thank you.

Comment: Hi @ChauNguyen , then just convert the tag of the object `"*info"` to `"xxx_*info"` as an example.

Comment: Hi @barbaros,  but I still like to have the object name output info still employee, address, officeinfo without the prefix "xxx_" except the type? Is there any split condition that can applied within the type if/else to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: Hi @barbaros, one thing i notice that if i added any character prefix to the type condition and change the condition properly as well, i dont get the result. That's what I dont understand.  can you explain a bit if this is not take much your time. Thanks, Chau

Comment: @ChauNguyen you can alternatively use `"*_*": { "@1": "@(5,type).&(1,2).&2" }` in order to get `"officeInfo" : {"type" : "xxx_officeInfo"}` whenever `type = xxx_officeInfo`

Comment: Great! Thanks @barbaros, yes it works with your suggestion!